# Navbar Dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a website for my teacher, and I want to have a drop down menu under a nav bar item, to list all of the classes he teaches. This is what I have so far:

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway';
 #bluebar {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
}
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 53px;
  top: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
li {
  float: right !important;
}
#navbut {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 19px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}
#navbut:hover {
  background-color: #1E90FF;
}
/*#myDropdown {
      z-index:1;
      visibility:hidden;
      opacity:0;
      filter:alpha(opacity=0);
      -webkit-transition:200ms ease;
      -moz-transition:200ms ease;
      -o-transition:200ms ease;
      transition:200ms ease;
    }
    
    #myDropdown:hover {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    }*/

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: visible;
  width: 150px;
}
#dropbut {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 19px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  width: 150px;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}
#dropbut:hover {
  background-color: #1E90FF;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mraz' Site</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="bluebar">
  </div>
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-right">
      <li><a id="navbut" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a id="navbut" class="dropbtn" href="#">Classes</a>
        <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a id="dropbut" href="#">AP Calculus AB</a>
          <a id="dropbut" href="#">AP Calculus BC</a>
          <a id="dropbut" href="#">Honors Statistics</a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a id="navbut" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm not entirely sure how to make the dropdown have an animation (slide in and out on hover over "Classes" button, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Also any tips on organization/ cleaning up my code. I'm fairly new to coding so help is always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done stuff with Jquery before?

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

When it comes to interactivity Jquery is pretty simple to get your head around.

Regarding doing a show/hide effect on the nav, check out 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

(I know these arn't code examples, but teaching someone to fish is better than giving them a fish)